# Is it possible for me to make my controller return data for my modal window? MVC5 ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Im busy making my ASP.NET web-app.

I will start with explaining the flow of my application.

- User submits form
- Form data gets posted to controller
- Controller generates table with numbers in it using tagbuilder, returning it as mvcHtmlString.

Every number in this table is surrounded by an anchor tag (a).
When this number is clicked i want to open a modal window that shows data relevant to the number being clicked.
Clicking this number currently has an url.action as href so it jumps into my controller, passing the number to the controller.

Showing the modal is not a problem since i can just pass a data-toggle and a data-target into my anchor tag, but i want to show data that the controller returns in it's body.

What i am currently doing is in my view which contains the form i do

`@{Html.RenderPartial("_Details");}`

`_Details` contains the whole modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="competenceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="competenceModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Competence details</p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My anchor tag being returned to the view containg the form:

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
var url2 = url.Action("LevelDetails", "Knowledge", new { level = level.Value });

var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
anchor.Attributes.Add("href", url2);
anchor.Attributes.Add("data-target", "#competenceModal");
anchor.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "modal");
```

This is correctly acessing my controller, but my big question is:

Is it possible to make the controller return data, such as a `mvcHtmlString` or any other content and put it in the body of my modal window? If so, what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: I would look into `return PartialViewResult("_Details");` which might help

Comment: I actually did, it returned me the modal header footer and close button, but in a raw format. It gave me a blank page with plain text and a button. It did not behave as a normal modal window would.

Comment: @Mick how did you called your method? Using AJAX?

Comment: No, using the Url.Action i created in my last code snippert.

Comment: I would try using an ajax request to get html data from the controller, i'd then place the html inside the modal as i see fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you following things,
1. Use **data-id** field while building your modal link in controller. Like **data-id="1"**.
2. In your partial view use this id to call an ajax method like "getData"
3. Return your data in json format from "getData".
4. Now bind that returned data to your form controls using jquery.

Hope this helps you !